# Failed to create COM object 'X': Class not registered in another WAMP

Tags: php, windows, apache, com, wamp

There already is a working WAMP instance in a Windows 7 in which the line

```
$x = new COM("X");
```

does instantiate a COM object.

I was trying to locate a bug, and decided to use a fresh new WAMP installation on the same Windows 7 system as the previous one.

In the new one, the same line produces:

```
Failed to create COM object 'X': Class not registered ( Error code: 0x80040154 )
```

Now, since the first WAMP comes with it's own installation application (along with its DLL which holds the COM class) I can't exactly figure out what I need to change in the new WAMP so the line above will instantiate the object.

- My WAMP version is: 2.2 and
- Apache version : 2.2.21
- PHP version : 5.3.10

Any idea what I need to set up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by changing the working directory (using `chdir`) to be the same as the `php.exe` just before `$x = new COM("X");`.

I think the DLL wasn't propery registered, or lacked something in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the DLL, using

```
regsvr32 yourdll.dll
```

Comment: Exactly why I said that "There already is a working WAMP instance in a Windows 7 in which the line $x = new COM("X"); does instantiate a COM object." so that means, the DLL is already registered, right?

Comment: Oh, these are on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same machine.