# C# Com Class works from VBS script but not from PHP

Tags: c#, php, vbscript, com

I have created a C# Com class. It's named ComClassExample.ComClassExample. The following VBS script can interact with the COM class:

```
dim objTest, intResult
Set objTest = WScript.CreateObject ("ComClassExample.ComClassExample")

intResult = objTest.add (1,2)
```

However, when I try the same thing in PHP, it doesn't work:

```
$com = new COM("ComClassExample.ComClassExample");
```

This gives me the error:

```
com_exception: Failed to create COM object `ComClassExample.ComClassExample': Class not registered
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be? I know the COM class can be accessed by 32-bit processes as I used %windir%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe to run my VB script.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449897/failed-to-create-com-object-x-class-not-registered-in-another-wamp

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Thanks, but I've already seen that one. Neither of those solutions worked...